# OpenCV calcOpticalFlowFarneback source code

Tags: python, opencv, opticalflow

Where can I find the Python source code for OpenCV calcOpticalFlowFarneback (https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-alpha/modules/video/doc/motion_analysis_and_object_tracking.html)? 
I tried looking up various sources and documentations but I couldn't find a reference to the code. I also browsed through OpenCV github repository but was unable to find it. 
Can some please refer me to it?

Basically, I want to know if there is any 3D implementation of Optical Flow Farneback or any other dense optical flow. I have realized that OpenCV calcOpticalFlowFarneback  is only applicable for 2D images.

Comment: OpenCV source code is in C++ only. All the bindings (i.e Python, JavaScript etc) call the C++ code internally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by zindarod, the opencv code you execute under the hood is c/c++ with som lower level languages/libs as well for optimizations, depending on your platform (cuda, opencl, TBB, IPP). The optical flow code you asked for especially is implemented here in its simplest form:

[opencv/modules/video/src/optflowgf.cpp](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/2da96be217ab437de854aca7f7670c2048fb554b/modules/video/src/optflowgf.cpp)

You can assume it is this code that actually executes at all times when you are running your python scripts with Farnebäck flow